# Dynamically added Views not appearing

Tags: android, android-activity

In my main activity, I call the following to display a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, FindActivity.class );
startActivity( intent );
```

This calls my `onCreate()` code within my `FindActivity` shown below:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
  {
    Utils.LogDebugf( "FindActivity:: onCreate()\n" );
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    mActivity = this;

    mBaseLinearLayout = new LinearLayout( mActivity );
    mBaseLinearLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ContextActivity.screenWidth, ContextActivity.screenHeight ) );
    mBaseLinearLayout.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );
    mBaseLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor( Color.TRANSPARENT );

    mEditText = new EditText( mActivity );

    mEditText.setWidth( ContextActivity.screenWidth );
    mEditText.setHeight( mResultLabelHeight );
    mEditText.setBackgroundColor( Color.DKGRAY );
    mEditText.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );
    mEditText.setText( "" );
    mEditText.setTextColor( Color.YELLOW );
    mEditText.setTextSize( 30 );
    mEditText.setSingleLine();
    mEditText.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );

    mEditText.setOnClickListener( buttonListener );
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener( mTextWatcher );

    mListView = new ListView( mActivity );
    mListView.setBackgroundColor( Color.WHITE );
    mListView.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );

    mBaseLinearLayout.addView( mEditText );
    mBaseLinearLayout.addView( mListView );
}
```

My Activity is declared as follows:

```
public class FindActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, ListChooserDialogListener
{
```

The problem I have is that none of my views/controls appear. I have a black sceen. What am I missing?

Comment: You've not actually added your `View`s to the `Activity`; e.g., `setContentView(mBaseLinearLayout);`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Mike, of course - you're a lifesaver! Turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept your answer. I copied this code from a class which was a View so the setContentView() would have been missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're not using an XML layout for your `Activity`'s content, you'll still need to call `setContentView()` for your dynamically created `View`s to be attached to the `Activity`. For example:

```
setContentView(mBaseLinearLayout);
```

Just make sure to pass the root `View` there, otherwise you'll get an `IllegalStateException`.